# How to break down multidimensional array into smaller array?

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have this multidimensional array in PHP...

```
$team1 = Array
         ( [0] => Array
               (
                    [player_num] => 87,
                    [team] => "penguins",
                    [last_name] => "crosby",
                    [first_name] => "sydney",
                    [rating] => 95,
               )
           [1] => Array
               (
                    [player_num] => 13,
                    [team] => "red wings",
                    [last_name] => "datsyuk",
                    [first_name] => "pavel",
                    [rating] => 94,
               )
           [2] => Array
               (
                    [player_num] => 55,
                    [team] => "red wings",
                    [last_name] => "kronwall",
                    [first_name] => "niklas",
                    [rating] => 89
               )
           [3] => Array
               (
                    [player_num] => 67,
                    [team] => "predators",
                    [last_name] => "weber",
                    [first_name] => "shea",
                    [rating] => 6,
               )
         )
```

I've created this array from a SQLite database using PDO. My issue is that I want to read this array in and then break it down into individual arrays, so that each player is its own array that then can be further broken down and used to add information to a player object that I've created in PHP. **The main question is how do I take this multidimensional array and break it down into individual arrays?**

So far I have this code that just separates the keys from the values...

```
foreach ($teamRed as $team=>$player) {
    echo "$team Value:<br>";
    foreach ($player as $key=>$value){
        echo "$key: $value<br>";
}
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: instead of echo in the foreach, assign what you want to an new variable

Comment: What do you want to do? In plain English (programming terms). You question, as it is, doesn't make any sense. You can extract each item in the array, sure... but what are you going to do with them? Where are you going to store them? Another array? Are you going to create an infinite amount of variables to store each node in? You see where I'm going with this? What are you trying to accomplish? *Then*, we can help you out (and maybe rephrase the title and question).

Comment: Seems like an odd request. Each player is already its own array - stored in `$team1[0]`, `$team1[1]`, `...` . Everything you need to do can be done with the data in its current form. Am I misunderstanding your question?